# Two functions on onChange()

Tags: react-native

I have a TextInput:

```
<TextInput
  ref='edit'
  style={{height:60, borderColor:'gray', borderWidth:1, backgroundColor:'white', borderRadius:10, margin:30}}
  onChangeText={function(text){
    this.setState({busca: text}) //<<ERROR HERE
    if (this.state.busca.lenght >= 13){
      onSubmitEditing={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Resultado', {busca: this.state.busca})}
  }
  }}
  onSubmitEditing={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Resultado', {busca: this.state.busca})}
  autoFocus
/>
```

When I try to execute two functions, receive an error

> undefined is not a function

but if I put only one function `onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({busca: text})}` this works

Comment: why are you trying to set the same state property to two different things?

Comment: this is an example. I like to do other function. I will edit the post

Comment: @m_callens I edit the post now

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo Kindly check the updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<TextInput
  ref='edit'
  style={{height:60, borderColor:'gray', borderWidth:1, backgroundColor:'white', borderRadius:10, margin:30}}
  onChangeText={text => this._useText(text)}
  }}
  onSubmitEditing={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Resultado', {busca: this.state.busca})}
  autoFocus
/>
```

And create a function that does any number of things you want:

**EDIT:**

```
_useText = text => {
   // Make use of text
   this.setState({ busca: text});
   // UPDATE: You shouldn't use the state variable instantly after you set it or you will get an error/old value, reason: the state is not updated yet.
   if(text.length >= 13){
       this.props.navigation.navigate('Resultado', {busca: text})
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass one handling function into the prop, so just create a wrapping function in the component like below and call that.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  handler(text) {
    this.setState({ busca: text })
    otherFunction()
  }

  render() {
    <TextInput
      ref='edit'
      style={{height:60, borderColor:'gray', borderWidth:1, backgroundColor:'white', borderRadius:10, margin:30}}
      onChangeText={this.handle.bind(this)}
      onSubmitEditing={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Resultado', {busca: this.state.busca})}
      autoFocus
    />
  }
}
```